# How to update the text attribute of Kivy Label dynamically using bind

Tags: python, dynamic, label, kivy, kivy-language

My question is simple and straight forward. I am trying to dynamically update a widget's attribute using `bind` function in Kivy. **Is it possible? And how?**

**Overview**:

The following snippet is a basic Kivy app that adds a `Label` widget with some text to the screen. It works! But if I wanted to use bind to change the text dynamically (as you can see with the commented line), I get the following error message:

`AssertionError: 'Updated Text' is not callable`

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        my_label = Label(text='Initial Text')
        # my_label.bind(text='Updated Text')
        return my_label


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**PS:**
I've seen all related questions and done lots of research online, including using callbacks that are callable to attributes (i.e. `on_press`, `on_press` etc). However, I couldn't find an answer for my specific question. 
I am hoping someone will guide me to the right answer and maybe touch on how Kivy/Python deal with dynamic widget modification since I am still new to them.

Thank you

Comment: The `bind` statement binds an `event` to a `method`. What `event` do you want to bind to, and what `method` do you want called when that `event` happens?

Comment: @JohnAnderson oh! In this case no event, I guess. I only want to update the `text` attribute.

Comment: Then you just set the `text` attribute to whatever you want. For example, `my_label.text='new text'`, but that will only work in the `builld` method because `my_label` is local to that method. Elsewhere, you will need to have a reference to the `Label` instance. Since, in your example, the `Label` is the `root` of the `TestApp` display, you can change the text using `App.get_running_app().root.text='new text'`, or if you do it in a method of `TestApp`, it could be `self.root.text='new text'`.

Comment: What a naive question, and what a great answer!! ty @JohnAnderson. Could you please post this as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just set the text attribute to whatever you want. For example,

```
my_label.text='new text'
```

but that will only work in the build method because `my_label` is local to that method. Elsewhere, you will need to have a reference to the `Label` instance. Since, in your example, the `Label` is the root of the `TestApp` display, you can change the text using

```
App.get_running_app().root.text='new text'
```

or if you do it in a method of `TestApp`, it could be

`self.root.text='new text'`

You can also use binding, typically by creating a `StringProperty` and binding to that property. The bound method would be code that sets the `text` attribute of the `Label` to the changed `StringProperty`. This can all be done in `Python`, but is more often (and more easily) done in a `kv` file:

```
ScreenManager:
    myText: 'Abba'
    Screen:
        name: 'the_screen'
        Label:
            text: root.myText
```

The `myText: 'Abba'` line creates a `StringProperty` in the `ScreenManager`. The `text: root.myText` line sets the initial `Label` `text` to "Abba", and arranges the above mentioned binding for you. So anytime the `myText` property of `ScreenManager` is changed, the `Label` `text` will automatically be updated to the changed `StringProperty`.